# Why does IsWellFormedOriginalString fail on file Uris?

Tags: c#, .net, uri

I have code like this:

```
string uriString = @"C:\Temp\test.html";
Uri uri = new Uri(uriString);
bool goodCond = uri.IsWellFormedOriginalString();
```

But goodCond is false! What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit:
Thanks Johannes and Catdirt. I'll focus my question: **How do I convert a valid file path to a valid file Uri** (using uri.IsWellFormedOriginalString as an indication to the validity of the Uri)? 
Take a look at this:

```
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp");
        FileInfo [] fis = di.GetFiles("test.html");
        FileInfo fi = fis[0];
        string uriString = fi.FullName;
        Uri uri = new Uri(uriString);
        bool goodCond = uri.IsWellFormedOriginalString()
```

Obviosly fi.fullName is a well formed path, but still goodCond is bad!

Comment: What language/environment is that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your URI is not well-formed.

A well-formed example would be `file:///C:/Temp/test.html`.

```
PS Home:> (new-object Uri 'file:///C:/Temp/test.html').IsWellFormedOriginalString()
True
PS Home:> (new-object Uri 'file:///C:\Temp\test.html').IsWellFormedOriginalString()
False
PS Home:> (new-object Uri 'C:\Temp\test.html').IsWellFormedOriginalString()
False
PS Home:> (new-object Uri 'C:/Temp/test.html').IsWellFormedOriginalString()
False
```

Comment: Hacked this:
  Debug.Assert(thePath.StartsWith(@"C:\"));
  string reversed = thePath.Replace(@"\", @"/");
  string uriSeed = @"file:///" + reversed;
  Uri resUri = new Uri(uriSeed);

Answer (score 1):

It's false because it's not well formed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformedoriginalstring.aspx